# Disable x Many Future Days after Today On DatePicker Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**EDIT**

I have a date picker with the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datePicker">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckoutDate, new {@id = "checkoutDate", @class = "form-control", @onChange = "Checkout.OnDateChanged()"})
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the date picker is initialized as

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: new Date()
    });
```

It works well and disables all past days.
I need to now limit the days selectable to **x** many future days from today. I've tried adding:

```
maxDate: 2
```

to the above to limit selection to two days in the future as described in many posts and documentation, but to no affect. This is the first time I'm fiddling with a date picker so chances are I'm just missing something really obvious...

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not increasing the `startDate` to today + 2 days?

Comment: No, that's the opposite of what I'm looking for. I need all previous days disabled, i.e. `startDate: new Date()`, x days after today to be enabled and then all other future days disabled, i.e. `maxDate: "+2"`

Comment: Oh ok, misread your question.

Comment: What is the MVC @onChange `Checkout.OnDateChanged()` doing? Is this interfering with the DatePicker? The options you describe seem to work fine in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5weyrmk/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `endDate: '+2d'` worked!
Thanks for everyone's suggestions :)

Have a lovely day.

Comment: In that case your using bootstrap-datepicker not jqueryui datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Try the string format for [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate):

> **String**: A string in the format defined by the [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option, or a
>   relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs;
>   valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and
>   `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven
>   days from today.

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: "+2d"
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the string format as described by you and the documentation. Still no change unfortunately...